# Dart/Flutter PetitParser Fails to Ingest

Tags: flutter, dart, petitparser

Having trouble again getting a my input properly ingested, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The full file I'm using to to define my lexers can be [seen here](https://github.com/fhir-fli/fhir_path/blob/antlrish/lib/fhirpath_lexer.dart). But specifically what I'm running into is that it won't identify an expression within parentheses. My issue is specifically with this Lexer:

```dart
Parser fhirPathExpression() {
  final _expression = undefined();
  final _invocation = undefined();
  final _function = undefined();
  final _paramList = undefined();

  final Parser expressionPart = (_invocation |
          (literal & char('.') & _invocation) |
          _function |
          literal |
          string('\$this') |
          string('\$index') |
          string('\$total') |
          externalConstant |
/// ******* line is the issue ***********************
          (char('(') & _expression & char(')'))) &
/// ***********************************************
      (identifyingOperations |
              (operations & _expression) |
              (char('.') & _invocation))
          .star();

  /// | (IDENTIFIER)? '=>' expression #lambdaExpression

  /// invocation : // Terms that can be used after the function/member invocation '.'
  final Parser invocationPart = ((_function |
          identifier |
          string('\$this') |
          string('\$index') |
          string('\$total')) &
      (char('.') & _invocation).star());

  final Parser functionPart = ((pattern('A-Za-z').plus().flatten().where(
                      (value) => noArgumentFunctions.keys.contains(value)) &
                  string('()'))
              .map((value) {
            return noArgumentFunctions[value[0]]!;
          }) |
          (pattern('A-Za-z')
                  .plus()
                  .flatten()
                  .where((value) => argumentFunctionNames.contains(value)) &
              char('(') &
              _paramList.optional() &
              char(')')))
      .map((value) => value);

  final Parser paramListPart = _expression & (char(',') & _expression).star();

  _expression.set(expressionPart.end());
  _invocation.set(invocationPart);
  _function.set(functionPart);
  _paramList.set(paramListPart);
  return _expression;
}
```

And I'm trying to parse "(1.2 / 1.8)". When I attempt this, I get this error:

```
FhirPathInvalidExpressionException (Expression could not be parsed: end of input expected
[
Expression: (1.2 / 1.8)
Offset: 5
Cause: Instance of 'ParserException': end of input expected (at 1:6)
])
```

The thing that confuses me is if instead I parse "(1.2 / 1.8", and change the offending line to:

```dart
(char('(') & _expression)) &
```

It works fine. Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I can't spot an obvious problem from glancing over your code. You could follow [Debugging your Grammars](https://github.com/petitparser/dart-petitparser?tab=readme-ov-file#debugging-your-grammars) to see a trace of how the input is processed. Also I would recommend that you write unit test for every production the expression depends on, to make sure every individual part behaves as expected.

Comment: Ahh actually I think you want to replace `_expression.set(expressionPart.end());` with `_expression.set(expressionPart);` and `return _expression;` with `return _expression.end();` as otherwise you expect the end-of the input within all referenced expressions.